# Unstable result for LDA cross-validation in R

Tags: r, lda

I have a little problem regarding the cross-validation function `lda(..., CV = TRUE)` as implemented in R package MASS.

The example 'test1' below I can run several times and always get the same value for pa (= the probability of accurate classification) but if I am running this script with my own data set I get several different results for pa.

Does anyone why data set might produce different results?

As far as I know the result should be stable since the cross-validation in this lda-function should be a jackknife re-sampling which systematically leaves out one observation/row each time, calculates the LDA with the rest, evaluates the discriminate functions using the left out observation/row and repeats this until every observation/row has been left out once.

I was also thinking about collinearity as a reason for this but for me this somehow does not fit to this problem ...

Unfortunately I do not know of any standard dataset implemented in R that reproduces this problem ...

Many thanks in advance.

```
#test1 (without problem)
library(MASS) #load MASS
data(iris) #load stardard dataset
pred <- lda(formula = Species ~ ., 
          data = iris, 
          prior = c(1,1,1)/3,
          CV = TRUE) #run LDA with equal priors
ct <- table(iris$Species, pred$class) #make a crosstable to see crassification success
pa <- sum(diag(prop.table(ct))); pa #summarize the diagonal (=correct classifications) 
# from the corresponding probalility crosstable and print the result
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but if you run everything below #test2 repeatedly, the `rnorm` will produce a different dataframe each time.

Comment: Oh ****! 
Yes, it was my failure this is a wrong example ... I will try to reformulate that question.